# max(column_name) is returning same value whne the load is heavy on database

Tags: sql-server

The below query is continously hit and records are getting inserted in the table `"TRANSACTION_MAIN"` but `@confrm` which is a number more than `max(TRN_CNFRM_NBR)` is same for couple of transactions, This behaviour is seen only when the load is too high on the DataBase server. Any insights into this, Why this behaviour is being observed, what might be happening behind the scenes?

```
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
            DECLARE @Confrm as int;
            SET @Confrm = (SELECT isnull
            (MAX(CONVERT(int, TRN_CNFRM_NBR)),0) 
            FROM TRANSACTION_MAIN WHERE
            TRN_UC_LOC = @1) + 1;

            DECLARE @TMID as int;

            INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_MAIN(
                TRN_CNFRM_NBR
                ,TRN_UC_LOC
                ,TRN_STAT_ANID
                ,TRN_SRC_ANID
                ,PRSN_ANID
                ,TRN_DT
                ,TRN_ACTL_AMT
                ,TRN_MTHD
                ,TRN_IP_ADDR
                ,DSCT_CD
                ,TRN_PAID_AMT
                ,CSHR_ANID
                ,INVDEPTEQUIP_ANID
                ,TRN_CMNT
                ,CPN_DSCT_TOTAL
            )
            VALUES(@Confrm,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12,@13,@14);

            SET @TMID = @@IDENTITY;");

               COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this isn't safe, so it shouldn't be a surprise that it doesn't work.

There's a few contributors to the final result. First, simultaneous selects for the max value will of course return the same value, because the "new" rows haven't been inserted yet. Second, depending on the transaction isolation level, the select doesn't see a row that has been inserted, but not committed yet.

As a quick fix, it should help to simply set the transaction isolation level higher. This will of course reduce your throughput and increase the risk of deadlocks, but at least it will be correct. Or, if you're on an SQL server high enough, use sequences. Or thread-safe CLR code.

And if you're stuck on an old SQL server and can't handle the higher transaction isolation, you can try implementing this using your own sequences, where incrementing the sequence is an atomic operation. There's a nice example in Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle.

Comment: setting "transaction isolation level higher" means setting it to "Read Uncommitted"?

Comment: @VinayKumar.o No, that's the oposite direction - `read uncommitted` is more relaxed than `read committed`. You probably need `serializable`.

Comment: Can you please provide the link for "Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle" where you are referring the sequence generation technique. We are also thinking in the same lines of using a sequence but since this column "TRN_CNFRM_NBR" is an existing column of type varchar we are finding difficulty in making this an identity column.  If you have any ideas in this regard please share.

Comment: @VinayKumar.o It's the very first result when you search google for that exact phrase :) The question is what you want your sequence to look like, and how much control you need over its generation - if `identity` fits your requirements, go with that. It's high performing, painless and reliable.

Comment: Thanks Luaan, The sequence i want is just a number, currently its max value is 60087. And identity does not fit my requirement because the column is existing and being used and there is already an identity column in the table "TRN_ANID"(transaction-id)? You might be wondering why are we not using the existing identity column. This is a legacy application we are handling and we need to adjust the problem :(

Comment: @VinayKumar.o Well, you could store the old `TRN_CNFRM_NBR` value in another column, and make a new `TRN_CNFRM_NBR` that's computed as `coalesce(TRN_CNFRM_NBR_OLD, TRN_ANID + someOffset)`. This will keep all the old numbers there, and have the new ones based on the identity column.

Comment: Thank you so much for your ideas and support. There is one more complexity attached to implement the above said solution. If you observe the statement used to calculate @confirm variable, the confirmation number is a sequence based on TRN_UC_LOC.

Comment: @VinayKumar.o Yeah, I'd go with a separate sequence table then, one row per `TRN_UC_LOC`. It's a lot easier (and less breaking) to get an exclusive lock on that, and with a unique constraint on the `TRN_UC_LOC` row it's quite easy to handle the new sequence case as well. Just do a `select` `with (rowlock, updlock)` in a transaction with the `update` of the same row, and you'll have a decent sequence.

Comment: Can you please illustrate with an example.

Comment: Hi, I figured out how to approach this, We are using sql 2008 r2 so we directly don't have option to use SEQUENCE object. So i am going to use a table for generating sequence with one identity column and we are currently working with 3 locations/vendors so for each vendor we create separate sequence table and use them. `BEGIN TRAN
INSERT INTO dbo.TRN_CNFRM_SEQUENCE_UC_LOC_1 
       output inserted.id into @confirm -- table variable
DEFAULT VALUES
ROLLBACK TRAN
select ID from @confirm-- table variable.` But i am concerned if we should look at any performance issues?

Comment: @VinayKumar.o Why are you doing the `rollback`? It can reset the identity, which will mean you'll use the uniqueness again. If you don't want the table to grow, just do a `truncate table`. And no, it shouldn't be a performance issue. It does have a scaling issue, though - you'll need to add tables as you add new locations.

Comment: No it is not resetting the identity, every time i execute the above query no record is inserted in the sequence table but i am getting the `inserted.id` as a sequence. So identity is maintained.

Comment: @VinayKumar.o Are you sure? I'm pretty convinced that if possible, it will reset the identity as well (e.g. if there's no other transaction in progress on the table). Maybe this changed in some MS SQL version, but you probably want to test it well to make sure it actually works.

Comment: Found this idea from this blog and it is working.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askjay/archive/2012/10/08/sequence-objects-in-sql-2012-and-sql-2008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the addition of 1.
The Query should like this:

```
SET @Confrm = (
        SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CONVERT(INT, TRN_CNFRM_NBR)), 0) + 1 -- you should add 1 here.
        FROM   TRANSACTION_MAIN
        WHERE  TRN_UC_LOC = @1
    );
```

Comment: when executed, both the queries give the same result but writting query as suggested by you will give any benefit in realtime?